# why does Netlify refuse to deploy my website?

Tags: netlify

i am trying to deploy a web site on Netlify.  unfortunately i received this

```
 stan: failed connecting to 'nats-aws-jfk'
```

what does that mean, and what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently an ongoing incident on Netlify. Builds may stuck a while because of this.

Incident Report: https://www.netlifystatus.com/incidents/92wdj5gyqdcn